# mysql return rows in order of IN() Id's

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

if I have an array of mysql row Id's like this:

```
$id_array = array(5,3,13,7,12);
```

How can I tell mysql to retrieve the id's with the title while preserving the order of the array.

i.e. something like:

```
$in = implode(',',$id_array);

$query = "SELECT `id`,`title` FROM table WHERE `id` IN($in) ORDER BY (order of $id_array)"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be looking for function [**FIELD**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
ORDER BY FIELD(field_name, implode(',',array(5,3,13,7,12)))
```

**Edit**

In your case it would be like.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, $in)
```

Comment: Nice one, except for the mixed php,sql syntax in the example. In OP's case it would look like `... ORDER BY FIELD (id,$in)`.

Comment: @Vatev well i have edited answer...i have given explanation about what to put...if i add id in first place then OP might get confused so i wrote `field_name` so OP do know about correct syntax.

Comment: I was talking about `implode(',',array(5,3,13,7,12))` in the sql statement, it looks like pseudocode atm. He will probably get the idea anyway, so its not a problem.

Comment: should that be $in not $id in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = implode(',',$id_array);

$query = "SELECT id,title FROM table WHERE id IN($in) ORDER BY id ASC";
```